# Why does redis-server service keep starting even after update-rc.d remove command?

Tags: 16.04, services, init.d, redis

I installed `redis-server` on Ubuntu 16.04 using `apt`.

It seems to auto-start at every boot-up by default

I don't like this, so I've tried the below commands:

```
sudo update-rc.d -f redis-server remove  # remove auto-start service
ls /etc/rc*.d | grep redis               # check service list, it prints nothing
```

It looks fine but redis-server is still auto-starting at every booting up.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the following command to disable the Redis server's service:

```
sudo systemctl disable redis-server
```

Comment: Thank you, it solves my issue.  what is different between `update-rc.d` and `systemctl` command?